# Problem with finding the kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T$ be a linear map which is represented by the following matrix in the standard basis.

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 4  \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm trying to find the kernel of the map $T$.
First I added row $3$ to row $1$ which gave me $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 4 & 2 & 3 \\ 6 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly this gives me $z=0.$ From here I then deduced that $y=-2x$ and so $$\ker T=\operatorname{span}\left \{\left(1,-2,0 \right)  \right \}$$

Can someone explain why this is incorrect?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you've done here. You should solve the homogeneous linear system $T\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of solutions in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I think your missing some steps so its hard to find where you went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are adding column 3 to column 1, which is incorrect. You can only do ROW reductions.

First switch row 2 to row 1 and switch row 3 to row 2, you get $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&4\\-1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Then add row 1 to row 3, and add (-2)row 1 to row 2, you get $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\0&-1&-2\\0&2&4\end{pmatrix}$

You can continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with: 
$A\mathbf x = 0$

$\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$

From the first row we an tell that $x_1 = x_3$
Arbitrarily, set them both equal to 1.

Multiply the next row, $4 + 2x_2 = 0, x_2 = 2$

And, check it with the 3rd row.